# How to parse json Data and display it using Ajax in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

There is an ajax call to system which returns JSOn as response and display it in HTML table.

In HTML we have following Code where data is to be displayed:

```
<table id="documentDisplay">
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th align="left">Document Type</th>
            <th align="left">File Name</th>
            <th align="left">Document Date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
```

Following is Ajax call and corresponding method call:

```
documentCommon.ajax({
        blockUI: false,
        type: 'POST',
        //dataType: 'html',
        url : 'loaddocument.json',
        data: {
            '_CONV_ID': $('input[name="_CONV_ID"]').val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            console.log(data);

            document.documentDisplay.clear().rows.add(data.lines).draw();
            //Here we get an error  
        },

    });



document.documentDisplay= $('#documentDisplay').DataTable($.extend({}, documentCommon.tableTemplate, {
            asStripClasses: [], // No stripes
            width:     "100%",
            scrollY: "150px",
            columnDefs: [
                {"width": "20%", targets: 0},
                {"width": "40%", targets: 1},
                {"width": "40%", targets: 2},
            ],
            columns: [
                {"data": "documentType"},
                {"data": "fileName"},
                {"data": "documentDate"}
            ]
    }));
```

Ajax is able to send request and bring back the data. Following is firebug output:

```
[
{
  "documentDate":[
     2015,
     8,
     18,
     13,
     1,
     51
  ],
  "documentType":"X",
  "documentId":18038,
  "fileExtension":"pdf",
  "filename":"kuka.pdf",
  "link":"http://something.com/kuka.pdf",
},
So on and end with ]
```

Following is error which is displayed in Firebug:

```
TypeError: a is undefined
```

Is there something wrong in code? Is there some other way to implement the same? Also, i want check on documentType in datatables i.e if documetType is X then display else do not display. Is there any way to do the same?

Comment: In your sample output there is no `lines` property, which you call in your code. Besides that, make sure both datatables and jquery are up to date. I had some problems in the past with version of both not matching.

Comment: @Sirko
Thanks. You are right there is no lines property. So i think i should pass only Data only but will datatables pick {"data": "documentType"} directly as it is? What more changes you suggest?

There is no version issue as many other places datatables is used and working fine and i am new to it so using it first time in combination.

Comment: Next problem are your names: In the table definition and the object you use different upper/lowercasing. I'm not sure, however, how datatables handle the array under `documentDate`.

Comment: I am able to display table by removing lines. Now issue is same handling of documentDate. I also have a check on documentType that to display document where type is X. Can you suggest on it?

Comment: You can run the whole data retrieval through a custom function by given to datatables. in that function you could change data formats etc as you like.

Answer (score -2):

if you are using jquery AJAX then you can directly get JSON data through : ***data.responseJSON*** in success callback of ajax call

Comment: User is already getting their data... They are wanting to structure it into a table..

Comment: the question was about json response that needs to be properly put in success callback, responseJSON already contains parse data so no need to decode the JSON string , but I dont think  my answer is out of context , although it does not answer but might be helpful for avoiding again decoding JSON object

Comment: and question was : How to parse json Data and display it using Ajax in JQuery? so I think my answer is not intended to be down voted , so question subject line matters

Comment: This is like telling someone you will teach them how to write a story, but only telling them step one which is grab some paper... and them already having paper and a pen.. In the context of the question.. Its not useful.. Further more its only a comments worth, not answer worthy